# How to debug a frame buffer application using gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, framebuffer

I am debugging a Linux frame buffer application with gdb. The problem is, ever since I entered into graphic mode, gdb is no longer available. What should I do? If gdb is not working in this case, what kind of debugging tool can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I do?

There are two standard approaches:

1. Use two monitors (gdb on one, frame buffer app on another), or
2. Use two computers and remote debugging (gdbserver controlling frame buffer on one computer, GDB on another).

> If gdb is not working in this case,

GDB should work just fine.

Comment: I have to use a slow way to debug my app, which is adding tracing information to logs. I have not try any of approach yet, because condition don't apply to me (Only 1 computer and 1 monitor), but that is what first comes to my mind too. Thanks though. I will set this as an answer. If any one find this is not working please let me know and I will change it (So it won't mislead other people in this case).